# How to get month first date and end date by given month?

Tags: postgresql, date

Based on Month I want to get start date and end date of that month. But I am getting current month start date and end date.

If I give 9 (month number) as input parameter.
Output should be:

```
2021-09-01 -- start date
2021-09-30 -- end date.
```

here my code is:

```
start_date =(select date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 year')::date);
end_date = (select date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 year')+'1month'::interval- 
            '1day'::interval as end_date);
```

output: 2021-10-01,2021-10-31

Answer (score 0):

You can use `make_date` to create the first of the month (for the current year), then use `+ interval '1 month - 1day` to find the last day:

```
start_date := make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, 9, 1);
end_date := (make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, 9, 1) + interval '1 month - 1day')::date;
```